Size of apartments in Sweden
Looking at apartment listings in Borås, Sweden, the first twelve range from eight to sixteen square meters.  This puzzled me because my friend's apartment in Spain was 55 square meters and was a comfortable (not luxurious) size.  So I looked again at Halmstad and see a range of 33 to 52 m².
Is Borås a special case, or do a lot of Swedish cities have such tiny apartments?

It may also be that you looked at the first page out of fifteen, sorted by the asking price. It stands to reason that the size of the apartment correlates with price. But, yeah, as nvoigt explained, student housing market tips the demand (and hence also the supply) towards the more economical end in college towns. It's the same in my native Finland.

Additionally some Internet listing sites are quite bad at telling apart apartments for rent from rooms for rent and often both get dumped in the same list.

Single point anecdote here, but as a Swede since 45 years I have never even heard of someone living in an apartment as small as 16 m² — including students.

The site you are browsing is really just aggregating offers coming from other sites (which seem to have themselves picked it up from somewhere else, and once again).
Once you reach the original description (for one of the smaller 8 m2 "apartments"), you end up here.
There, you find this description:

This student-room is furnished and the standard is simple and older.
You need to bring your own bed linen and kitchen utensils.
You share kitchen and bathroom with other students, both male and female.
We only allow 1 person per room.
Everything is including in the rent, the electricity, water, heat and internet connection through Splitvision. No Wifi. You need to bring a connecting cord.
Only for post-secondary education students in Borås.

So no, it's not really an apartment, but a room in a student accommodation. Cheap, reserved for students, shared bathroom and kitchen...
Outside of dedicated student accommodation of this form, there are also small studios which are rented to students, single people, etc. They would probably be slightly larger than 8 m2 though.
You have sorted your search results by price, so it's quite normal that the first ones are very small. That doesn't mean there aren't any larger ones, and by setting up a filter on a larger number of rooms you'll see those (that site is quite bad, it doesn't even allow filtering by size).
I'm pretty sure there must be better sites to search for apartments there. You probably want a local site rather than some international aggregator.

Indeed, I would prefer a local site, though I don't know how to find one. Can't read Swedish yet.  Searching in English, the first four or more hits are for short-term vacation rentals.  I doubt that it would do any good to search in Spanish or Italian.

@WGroleau Google translate (or the translation features of your browser) is your friend, I suppose. I wonder if there is canonical wiki answer with all the relevant sites by country…

DeepL is often better than Google, but I have to find the site first (or translate all the useless sites until I get to one that's worthwhile). –

I could live with a 10m² bedroom, but I'd rather have my own kitchen and bathroom.

I am going to take an educated guess here: The city has a renowned university and about 20% of its population is students of said university.
8-16m² sounds like a one-room student apartment. Tiny. But perfect if you don't have a job and just need to live somewhere while you are enrolled.
Many European cities have specialized their markets to students of universities. There should be enough "normal" apartments, but obviously student apartments have a higher turnover rate, with people coming and leaving, and are kind of seasonal. With the autumn semester about to start, they are probably in high demand.

I don't think Borås University is particularly renowned (except, apparently, for its School of Textiles), but it is indeed large (19000 students) for such a small city (74000 inhabitants). I second your points about turnover rate, and would add that student housing is particularly seasonal in Scandinavia (much more so than e.g. Germany) because there is a long summer break where nearly everybody is on holiday away from their place of study, and almost all students start their academic life in August.

I've got a feeling that most of the really small apartments (sub 20 square meters or so) are likely what are known in Britain as 'bedsits' and in North America as 'single-room-occupancies\SROs', which are like studio apartments, except the individual units lack ensuite bathrooms and kitchens, with those facilities being shared with other residents in the building.
